# 3 monitors with ATI card

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors

So I wanted to go back to Linux (Ubuntu) after been using windows for a while and went ahead and installed Ubuntu.

The problem that I got was I couldn’t use it the way I wanted, I have a 3 monitor setup and the left and right monitor is in portrait mode, and for some reason that didn’t work on Ubuntu, what I got was two monitors not showing anything when going in to display settings and changed them to portrait, I tried installing the ATI Catalyst and tired all the additional drivers that I could choose from, but that didn’t solve the problem.
So I had to go back to Windows. Anyone knows how to make this work so I might give it another go.

I’m using an ATI HD7850 card.

Comment: When you go into displays from System Settings what do you get? What is displayed? Does it show all three monitors?

Comment: Yes when i go into displays i see all 3 monitors but they are in landscape mode, when changing the 2 to portrait they stop working.